# Select columns based on text displayed on multiple TextBoxes

Tags: sql-server, wpf, select, checkbox

I am trying to create a user report generator feature.

I have a list of `CheckBoxes` that when `IsChecked` will show the `SQL Server` Column name from a table in from the database. I am then trying to use those names in my `SQL Statement` to generate the query results.

The issue I am facing is he user cannot select various column names because a `,` is needed in the SQL Statement to separate the column names. If the `CheckBox` is not checked, I do not want the column to display.

Here is my code that will execute the query results and populate the `DataGrid` where I am getting an exception error if both `textboxes` are filled with text. It works if only one is filled.

```
private void butn_ExecuteQuery_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = ("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + txtAccount.Text + txtAssignedTo.Text + " FROM [hb_Disputes] CROSS JOIN hb_FinAdj INNER JOIN Users ON hb_Disputes.ASSGNTO = Users.KY_USER_ID WHERE (hb_Disputes.OPENED >=@OPENED AND hb_Disputes.OPENED < @CLOSED) AND (Users.TX_EMPLOYEE =@query)", connection);
        //EMP Name
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", txt_Query.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OPENED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtepicker_Open.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CLOSED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtepicker_DateResolved.Text;

        connection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        connection.Close();

        dt_ReportList.DataContext = dt;
        dt_ReportList.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here is the code to handles when the `CheckBoxes` are `checked` and `unchecked`

```
private void chckAccount_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtAccount.Text = "[hb_Disputes].[ACCOUNT]";
}

private void chckAccount_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtAccount.Text = " ";
}

private void chckAssignedTo_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtAssignedTo.Text = "[hb_Disputes].[ASSGNTO]";
}

private void chckAssignedTo_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtAssignedTo.Text = " ";
}
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to do string concatenation logic with comas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether both textboxes have text and add the comma if they have:

```
private void butn_ExecuteQuery_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = ("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string account = txtAccount.Text;
        string assignedTo = txtAssignedTo.Text;
        if (account.Length > 1 && assignedTo.Length > 1)
            account += ",";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + account + assignedTo + " FROM [hb_Disputes] CROSS JOIN hb_FinAdj INNER JOIN Users ON hb_Disputes.ASSGNTO = Users.KY_USER_ID WHERE (hb_Disputes.OPENED >=@OPENED AND hb_Disputes.OPENED < @CLOSED) AND (Users.TX_EMPLOYEE =@query)", connection);

        ...

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly. Thank you so much.